# Write an output file superset of 3 files with no lines repeated in it

Tags: regex, perl

I have three text files 1.txt, 2.txt and 3.txt, which are outputs of a perl script. There are some common lines in all the 3 files. Please help to write a perl script whose output is another text file which is superset of 1.txt and 2.txt and 3.txt and should not have lines repeated in it.

Comment: are the lines perhaps in some sorted order?  or not?  how big are the three files (in lines and bytes)?

Comment: `cat file{1,2,3}.txt | sort -u` ??

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use a hash to keep track of lines you've seen before.  For very large files, this will take too much memory, however.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie 'open';

open my $out, '>', 'superset.txt';

my %seen;
for my $filename ('1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt') {
    open my $in, '<', $filename;
    while ( my $line = <$in> ) {
        print $out $line unless $seen{$line}++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl one liner for unique lines in `.txt` files,

```
perl -ne '$s{$_}++ or print' *txt > out.txt
```